# Master pages are ignoring the fact that I have deleted the CSS file

Tags: c#, html, css, asp-classic

I was trying to change the color of something in my website, so i went to my global.css and changed the hex value of the background and nothing changed, so I changed everything to black to see if anything happens, nothing changed, then I deleted the CSS file completely and the master pages/we pages still have CSS like before, it's like it's ignoring the fact that I deleted the CSS

Comment: Is your browser cached? Make sure you clear your cache.

Comment: Are there any other CSS files anywhere?

Comment: thanks setek, it was the browser.

Answer (score 0):

> Check the path of stylesheet in the browser.

This is a personal error caused by adding a stylesheet in header or template